# DropWizard without HTTP?

Tags: java, port, dropwizard

We've developed a significant project in DropWizard, but the nature of the project has shifted, and we're moving away from having actual HTTP endpoints and toward RabbitMQ. However, DropWizard has a lot of cool features we'd like to keep using, and besides the pain of replication, it would take a lot of worker hours to stop organizing things as (e.g.) DropWizard services.

With all that said: is it possible to run a DropWizard application without any open ports?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you very well can, see [here](https://github.com/code-monastery/dropwizard-rabbitmq) & [here](https://github.com/mbknor/dropwizard-activemq-bundle).

> DropWizard has a lot of cool features we'd like to keep
>   using

Which feature are you interested in?

Since Dropwizard is primarily built to serve HTTP traffic, it has Jetty & Jersey which will be initialised on your app startup, it doesn't make sense for your app to have these if you never plan to build an some sort of an API inside your app (say for custom-monitoring, health-checks etc.,).